# Pascal File: How do I find the MAX and MIN occurrences of an integer from a file?

Tags: file, max, pascal, lazarus, minimum

I am new to Pascal and have a sample.txt file with the following integers:

```
1 2 
2 1
1 3
3 1
1 4
```

How do I find the integer from the file with the minimum and maximum occurrences in Pascal language? In the above example, max occurrences would be the integer 1 (occurs 5 times) and minimum would be 4 (occurs once).

I understand I must open the file and read the values in and I've figured out this much so far. Is there a shorter way to perform this?

```
var
  V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8, V9, V10: Integer; 
begin 
  Assign(F, 'sample.txt');
  Reset(F);
  read(F, V1);  
  read(F, V2);
  read(F, V3);
  read(F, V4);
  read(F, V5);
  read(F, V6);
  read(F, V7);
  read(F, V8);
  read(F, V9);
  read(F, V10);

  writeln('Max Occurrence')
  writeln('Min Occurrence')

  Close(F);
  writeln;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a loop to read in the contents of the file. Do you know what a loop is?

Comment: How would you do it without a computer, using pencil & paper? Once you've figured that out, write the code to express it in Pascal.   Hint:  When you get to the coding, an `array` is a convenient data structure to use to store and process the data.  You can find the answers you need either by scanning the array or sorting it; both are elementary operations which you need to learn how to do.  You will learn nothing if someone simply posts a solution to your problem.

Comment: @MartynA: Actually, if you must constantly add items and if it is not sure upfront how many you will add, a list is a much better data structure. But a  list may be a little too much for a complete beginner.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis:  Sure, my first thought was a (linked) list - I have a pre-Delphi aversion to arrays - but, as you say, it would probably be a little too much for this exercise.

Comment: @MartynA: I meant a simple stock TList<Integer>, not a linked list. The linked list would be even farther above a beginner's horizon.

Answer (score 0):

Basically

```
 writeln('Max Occurrence',max(v1,max(v2,max(v3,max(v4,max(v5,max(v6,max(v7,max(v8,max(v9,v10)))))))))))
 writeln('min Occurrence',min(v1,min(v2,min(v3,min(v4,min(v5,min(v6,min(v7,min(v8,min(v9,v10)))))))))));
```

give or take a ")", 
but a teacher might not accept that as a solution without a loop, because it doesn't scale with the number of inputs.

The principle is that the final maximum is the maximum of the temporary maximum + the next  data item